# Similarity between spinless fermion and weakly interacting bosons

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Why do spinless fermions behave in the same way as weakly interacting bosons.

Comment: I thought fermions have to have a half integer spin; and frankly zero is not a half integer!!

Comment: @Ali The fact that fermions have half-integer spin doesn't keep them from behaving as bosons under certain specific conditions or in a specific model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They don't. A very obvious counterexample is the behaviour of alkali atom gases at temperatures low enough for quantum degeneracy to kick in.

At very low temperatures, bosonic atoms will interact weakly with each other via collisions. There is pretty clear experimental evidence that weakly interacting bosonic atoms form a [Bose-Einstein condensate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate) (BEC) at low temperatures. One can also do similar experiments with fermionic atoms, in which case they definitely do not form a BEC. Typically one uses a magnetic trap that only confines one spin state and not the other one, and therefore the system is pretty much perfectly spin-polarised (spinless fermion = spin-polarised fermion for those confused about spin-statistics). Due to the antisymmetry of the fermionic wave function in configuration-space, $s$-wave scattering is completely suppressed for a spin-polarised system. That means that at low temperatures the fermions are virtually non-interacting.

So in general, a spinless fermion system does not act in any way like a weakly interacting boson system. Perhaps the OP is referring to the well-known equivalence between non-interacting spinless fermions and hard-core bosons (i.e. bosons with an infinitely strong, short-range interaction) in 1D (the [Tonks-Girardeau limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonks%E2%80%93Girardeau_gas)).

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear answer. I was reading a paper http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.0870 where the authors claimed this statement. Why is the s-wave scattering in spinless fermions completely suppressed? Does that mean one cannot use Feshbach resonance to tune the interaction?

Comment: @Jeremy From looking at the paper, it seems the authors only made that claim in a very specific context: a sudden quench of an optical lattice potential; I couldn't tell you why the two types of exchange statistics behave similarly in that case.

Comment: @Jeremy About the scattering, consider just a two-fermion scattering problem. The wavefunction can be written as a product of a trivial centre-of-mass wavefunction and an interesting relative wavefunction $\psi(\mathbf{r})$, where $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}_1 - \mathbf{r}_2$ is the relative coordinate. Then we have $\psi(\mathbf{r}) = -\psi(-\mathbf{r})$ for spin-polarised fermions. The $s$-wave component of the relative wavefunction has no angular-dependence, implying that the $\psi_s(r=0) = 0$. Therefore scattering in the $s$ channel is suppressed since the interaction is short-range.

Comment: @Jeremy I couldn't tell you about Feschbach resonances. In principle I suppose it is possible to tune, for example, the $p$-wave scattering length via a resonance with a bound state. I have no idea how easy this is to do experimentally.